# Role required to display Add an account dialog

Tags: sitecore-client, security, role-management, permissions

Which of the standard Sitecore roles is required for a CMS user to view the 'Add an account' dialog via the Content Editor?

*Any Item* > Security > Assign security

Adding the user to the `sitecore\Sitecore Client Securing` role enables the 'Assign security' link, which opens the 'Assign Security Rights' dialog. But the 'Add' button does nothing when clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sitecore\Sitecore Client Securing` role grants access to features and applications used to **assign access rights**.

> Gives the user access rights to security features in the Content Editor and other relevant applications.
>
> This role is intended for users who need to maintain users and access rights.

You need to assign the `sitecore\Sitecore Client Account Managing` role in order to provide access to applications used to **maintain users, roles, and domains**.

> Gives the user access to maintain users, roles, and domains in the Access Manager, the Domain Manager, the Role Manager, and the User Manager.

Both `sitecore\Sitecore Client Securing` and `sitecore\Sitecore Client Account Managing` are members of the `sitecore\Sitecore Local Administrators` role.

These roles are described on the *Security Roles* Sitecore official [documentation page](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/the-security-roles.html):

Comment: This is now working as expected with only `sitecore\Sitecore Client Securing` being assigned. The odd behaviour I initially observed has been put down to a potential caching issue. Thanks for your clarification on this.